# XBee PRO S1 always gets response with API MODEM_STATUS_RESPONSE instead of nothing

Tags: c++, xbee, mbed

My wiring is this:
[image: XBee wiring]

XBee is configured in API mode 1 and mbed (LPC1768) runs this code:

```cpp
Serial terminal(USBTX, USBRX);

wait_ms(1000);

while(!terminal.readable()) {
  wait_ms(10);
}
terminal.getc();
mbed_led1 = 1;

while(1) {
  xbee.readPacketUntilAvailable();
  terminal.puts("Packet available\r\n");
  XBeeResponse response = xbee.getResponse();
  if (response.isAvailable()) {

    char tmp[20];
    int c = response.getApiId();
    sprintf(tmp, "%d", c);
    terminal.puts("Response available at API: ");
    terminal.puts(tmp);
    terminal.puts("\r\n");

    if (response.getApiId() == RX_16_RESPONSE) {
      Rx16Response rx16 = Rx16Response();
      response.getRx16Response(rx16);

      uint8_t len = rx16.getDataLength();
      char l[20];
      sprintf(l, "%d", len);

      terminal.puts("We have data: ");
      terminal.puts(l);
      terminal.puts("\r\n");
    }
  }
  wait(1);
}
```

XBee library for mbed is essentially a port of a widely popular Arduino XBee library. Sources are here: http://mbed.org/users/okini3939/code/XBee/

And when aforementioned code runs, my output is this:

```
Terminal ready
Packet available
Response available at API: 138
Packet available
Response available at API: 138
...
```

**138** is a decimal representation of a hex 0x8A, which in turn is mapped to MODEM_STATUS_RESPONSE.

This XBee module is the only one that is powered.

And my question is why would I have that weird behaviour? How come this XBee have successfully read packet at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XBee module sends the Modem Status frame to the host, and it's not the result of the module receiving a packet.  Try dumping the rest of the Modem Status frame to see what status the XBee module is trying to report.  It might be reporting Hardware Reset (0x00), followed by Coordinator Started (0x06).

The [XBee Series 1 documentation](http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000982_M.pdf) includes a list of all possible Modem Status values.

BTW, updating the `sprintf(tmp, "%d", c);` to use `"0x%02X"` as the format string will print the frame type in hex and make it easier to look up frame types in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try all your suggestions and report what I've got.

Comment: Dumping frame data indeed helped a lot. I got that issue since I forgot to turn off reset. I.e. I had 0x00 status, which is Hardware Reset. Although, I have yet another issue with communication, this particular issue is resolved and I am really appreciate for your hint and link to a doc.

Comment: @oddy what do you mean exactly by "I forgot to turn off reset" ? (I am currently also trying to diagnose an unexpected "hardware reset" modem status response)

Comment: He's probably referring to connecting the /RESET pin so it doesn't float.